# When i Update same table column with calculate another columns values

Tags: sql, oracle11g, oracle10g

```
Update dp2 a set a.amt= (select((b.qty*b.rate)-b.discount) from dp2 b where a.dpinheadid=b.dpinheadid)
```

Error Came

```
ORA-01427: single-row subquery returns more than one row
#For.Ex: TABLES DP2 A,DP2 B
(b.qty*b.rate)-b.discount) THIS VALUE Update TO This column A.AMT
```

Comment: Add some sample table data, both before and after versions. (As well formatted text, use `{}`.)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are trying to update a row with a `select` statement which returns **more than 1 row**.

This select:

```
select((b.qty*b.rate)-b.discount) from dp2 b where a.dpinheadid=b.dpinheadid
```

returns more than 1 result - so you cannot use it as an update value.

If you want to use it, you need it to return **a single value**, so try using a `WHERE` clause or `TOP 1` to return only the first result, etc.

Comment: And what's OP expected to do now?

Comment: Ya so only asked

Answer (score 0):

have you tried this query:

```
Update dp2 a set a.amt= a.qty*a.rate-a.discount
```

Comment: @siva Does it work? If yes feel free to accept my answer. If not please let me know